# Is there automatic name lookup for enumerators in c++?

Tags: c++, enums, scope, language-lawyer

As for as I know, currently in c++ there is no support for this.

For example,

```
class C{
    struct{
        enum {defaulted, opt1, opt2, ...} flag1;
        enum {defaulted, optA, optB, ...} flag2;
    } flags;
    ...
};
```

Now suppose we have `C obj`, to use the flag one would do

```
obj.flags.flag1 = obj.flags.opt1;
```

which is unnecessarily verbose.

However as the type of `obj.flags.flag1` is known, in theory the compiler could lookup the name `opt1` in that scope and save some typing.

Because the flags are not used anywhere else, it is preferred not to give names to the types (in fact it is difficult to come up with appropriate names). `using enum` syntax in c++20 does not solve this, because: it 1) requires the `enum` types to be named; 2) `using` multiple `enum`s may lead to name collision, as shown here, since both `enum`s have a `defaulted` member.

What will be the difficulties to implement this? Has this been proposed to the C++ standard committee and/or implemented in some compiler?

Comment: your argumentation against a named scope enum is a little moot. In your example both enums have a `defaulted` and without giving the enums a name you cannot distinguish them. And that is a problem already before you try to be less verbose

Comment: Short answer: no, it cannot be done without significant changes of the C++ type system, and the working of expressions.  The behaviour of an assignment expression is determined by the types of both its operands.  For an assignment `a = b` the type of both `a` and `b` are first determined, and the assignment succeeds (i.e. doesn't result in a diagnosable error) if the type of `b` is the same as, or can be implicitly converted to, the type of `a`.    You are seeking something fundamentally different - examining the type of `a` and then using that to infer some context for interpreting `b`.

Comment: @Peter Great. Can you write an answer so that I can accpet it?

Answer (score 2):

There could easily be an object named `opt1` that could be converted to the appropriate enumeration type.  It's better for name lookup to behave consistently rather than make special cases based on the types of other operands (partly because types are usually determined *after* name lookup).